# Open source Load Testing framework

Tags: testing

I am looking for a well maintained open source framework for load testing http services.   It would be nice if I could create arbitrary HTTP requests, control the rate of reqeusts and graph the resource consumption over time.  Ideally it would use SNMP to gather data from a remote server that it is testing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apache JMeter is good for load tests. http://jmeter.apache.org/ Has many features and a good graphical UI. Give it a try.

Another alternative that comes bundled in many Linux distros and OS X is `ab` tool.

There's also another program called `boom` originally written in Python (https://github.com/tarekziade/boom) and then in Go (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codecompileunit(v=vs.110).aspx).

But JMeter has tons of features and fancy reporting among all.

Comment: +1 with the caveat that if you need to use a client SSL cert there seems to be no way to do it automatically - the cert has to be manually attached through the GUI.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you can use ab ? (apache benchmark)

```
ab -c 100 -n 1000 http://yoursite.com/your_page.html
```

Will run 1000 times the request with 100 request in parallel.

Comment: I'm looking for something a bit more advanced.

Comment: httperf, autobench, openload ?

Answer (score 3):

I used to use apache bench (ab) but I moved to [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) lately and have been very happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

How about [loadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) ? I've used it several time, and it can handle a variety of web service types. Pretty good software, I think ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) is also a good open source Java based load testing framework.

- You can script your tests with Python or Clojure.
- It has a decent Swing GUI like JMeter.
- You can run multiple load injection instances, giving you a distributed load testing framework.
- It's extensible, since it has a plugin system.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to world of [Gatling.io](http://gatling.io/#/).

This is by far the best opensource load testing framework which I came across.
Advantages -

1. Test scenerios can be constructed using Gatling scripting framework or in Scala.
2. Clear, exhaustive, dynamic and colorful HTML reports after running the test cases -> analysis is helpful.
3. It provides high performance.
4. Support for HTTP, WebSocket protocols and JMS support also present. And any other protocol implementation is perfectly possible.
5. Gatling’s architecture is asynchronous and message based. Thus threads are not created for thousands of seperate users making it resource cheap.Running thousands of users simultaneous can be done at ease. -> *this makes it better than other opensource load testing frameworks*.
6. Realtime monitoring is also possible.
7. Documentation is good and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Visual Studio, no need to search for 'open source' solution, as you have a built-in solution included. Out-of-the-box it allows you to write code to 
"create arbitrary HTTP requests", "control the rate of reqeusts" and "graph the resource consumption over time" and also include agents you can use to distribute the load generation across multiple servers. I loved it.

See an intro [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amit_chatterjee/archive/2009/01/29/web-and-load-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Yandex.Tank](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank) is a framework for load tests. Features:

- It has modular plugin-based architecture, so it will be easy to extend it for your needs
- You can use different load generators (JMeter among them)
- There is a [report](https://github.com/yandex-load/yatank-online) plugin.
- [Autostops](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#autostop). You can stop your test automatically on different conditions.
- [HTTP API server](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank-api).
- InfluxDB and Graphite [support](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#graphite).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) - this is an open source framework that allows you to run many load testing tools such as JMeter, Grinder, Gatling, Apache Benchmark and more.
The cool thing about Taurus is that you get the functionality of each of these open sources tools and you can easily create the test scenarios using YAML or JSON formats!